# Python (Django): ImportError: No module named ' '

Tags: python, django, import

I have different scripts in the following diretory structure (see picture):

[image: Directory]

`crawl.py` imports script `db.py` from the same directory. However, I receive an error message: ImportError: No module named 'db'.

I tried to rename the script, but the same error still exists.

**crawl.py**

```
import db
import sys
import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime

def query(resource):
    r = requests.get('http://XX.XXX.XX.XX:8080/webapp/api/v1/' + resource,
        headers={'AuthenticationToken': 'XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX'}
    )
    return r

def crawlmain(formdata):
    costumer_id = 1
    production_number = formdata

d = query('productionOrder/?productionOrderNumber-eq={}'.format(production_number)).json()

session = db.Session()

costumer = session.query(db.Costumer).get(costumer_id)

if 'result' in d and len(d['result']) > 0:
    r = d['result'][0]
    order = db.Order()
    try:
        order.article_id = r['articleId']
        order.amount = r['targetQuantity']
        order.create_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(r['createdDate'] / 1000)
        order.start_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(r['targetStartDate'] / 1000)
        order.end_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(r['targetEndDate'] / 1000)
    except NameError as e:
        sys.exit('Error {}'.format(e.what()))

    article_number = r['articleNumber']
    d = query('article/?articleNumber-eq={}'.format(article_number)).json()

    if 'result' in d and len(d['result']) > 0:
        r = d['result'][0]
        article_image_id = r['articleImages'][0]['id']
        order.price_offer = r['articlePrices'][0]['price']

        r = query('article/id/{}/downloadArticleImage?articleImageId={}'.format(order.article_id, article_image_id))

        order.article_image = r.content
    else:
        print('No result for article with number', article_number)

    costumer.orders.append(order)

    session.add(costumer)
    session.commit()
else:
    print('No result for production order with article number', article_number)
```

It might be important to say, that the script runs without problems if carried out as a standalone script (though still stating the ImportError). However if embedded in my django environment, I can not call the script.

Anyone knows why this ImportError is occuring in the first place?
Thanks!

Edit: After changing the import statement to `from django import db` as suggested in the comments, I receive the following error: module 'django.db' has no attribute 'Sessions'

[Screenshot Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyK4X.png)

Comment: have you accidentally deleted or moved `db`?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint: No, db is still in the right directory

Comment: then `import django.db` should work or `from django import db`

Comment: Try adding `import sys` and `print(sys.path)` before `import db` to see where is _Python_ checking for modules.

Comment: @WhatsThePoint: Thanks, but now I'm getting an AttributeError: module django.db has no attribute 'Sessions'. I added a screenshot from the new error in my initial question.

Comment: It is  difficult to give advice on how to correctly use sessions here, for it is not entirely clear what is needed from them. However, should you want to use them -- here is how https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/ The error you get cause the db module has no class called Session that could be instantiated with  `session = db.Session()`

Comment: Please provide the **entire traceback** in the question itself, as plain text, for the code in the **original question**, not the modified one. The advice to change to `django.db` was not correct.